# Default value of a column based on other column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `mytable` table in my MySQL database.

It contains the following columns:

- **id (INT)** PRIMARY KEY - AUTO INCREMENT - DEFAULT NONE
- **name (VARCHAR (220))** - DEFAULT NULL
- **code (VARCHAR (220))** - DEFAULT NULL

Is it possible that if I insert something in this table I want the `code` column to autogenerate its value based on the columns `id` and `name`.

If I tried to run this example query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(name) VALUES ('myname');
```

I want to get the following result:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | code  |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | myname | my1   |
+----+--------+-------+
```

The `code` column default value must be the first 2 characters of `myname` which is `my` plus the `id` column.

I can actually do this using PHP code but I think there must be a way using MySQL only.

Comment: You have two options with and without auto increment on id  [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d650eb5e19d6faff82a1bf085926b7b)

Comment: I vote for PHP -- you will have more flexibility and you can respond faster to odd names that don't follow whatever algorithm you pick.

Comment: @Sam The value of calculated field cannot be altered :( if new value and calculated value are not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `code` field values are altered never the solution is trivial - look on the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d650eb5e19d6faff82a1bf085926b7b) provided in [Sam](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/153556/sam)'s comment. The only point I'd recommend to specify VIRTUAL attribute for calculated field explicitely.

If the `code` field values specified in a question are default only, and they can be altered from the default value freely either when inserting or by data updating, I'd recommend to make this field NULLable and use NULL value as a mark that the value is default one and must be calculated in a query. In all places where you need the value of this field you will use the below expression instead of direct field's value selection:

```
SELECT  ..., 
        COALESCE(code, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(name,1,2),id)) code, 
        ...
```